# Deleting a phone from iCloud

Tags: icloud

In the manage storage section on my phone, if I delete the backup of another phone from my iCloud, will I lose the pictures currently on my phone that were taken from this other phone?

Comment: you are deleting backup not the actual contents

Answer (score 1):

The photos will remain on your current phone. You're only deleting the backup of a different phone and not affecting the phone you're using at all.